# MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath MSBuild Property Could Not be Found When trying to Manage Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I've encountered a weird error today when trying to manage nuget packages on a unit test project in my solution:

[image: No property :(]

I took a look at the documentation for this property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019 and it mentions that this property is part of a props or a target file. My solution does not have one of these. I went ahead and modified the csproj to add the property:
`<MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath />` to the appropriate build propertygroup, and it didn't detect it either. I looked at another project that lets me work with nuget packages successfully and it doesn't have the property at all.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I gave up trying to figure it out. I created a new project and put in my code files/references.

Answer (score 2):

You probably accidentally removed the following line from your project file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: Nope, it is still there.

Answer (score 2):

`MSBuildProjectExtensionPath` is defined at Microsoft.Common.props

> <MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>$([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash($([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)', '$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'))))</MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>

So you may miss to import that file in your project begining.

> <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />